# Looping and selectig different value in each line

Tags: loops, spss

I have a problem that I think would be solved relatively quickly with a loop. I have to work with SPSS and I think it can only be solved in syntax.
Unfortunately I am not good with loops, so I hope that one of you can help me.
I have done a study on reasons for abortions. Now I would like to present the distribution of reasons.

The problem is that each person was first asked about all their pregnancies (because this is also relevant for the later analysis), then the pregnancy was determined to which the questionnaire will further refer.
So the further questionnaire was only about one of the pregnancies, whereas the first questions (f.ex. year of pregnancy, reason for abortion) were answered for each pregnancy. For the reasons I only need the information that refers to the pregnancy that was also used for the further questionnaire.

I have an index variable that determines the loop at which pass the relevant pregnancy is asked ("index"). Then I have the variable "Loop_1_R" to "Loop_5_R" which queries the reasons for each up to 5 abortions (of course, for each woman, only the number of pregnancies that she also indicated). In between there are some missing data, for ex. it could be that a woman said that she had 5 pregnancies, but only two of them were abortions (f.ex. the third and fifth). So then she would only give reasons for an abortion in loop3 and loop5.
Now I want to create a new variable which contains only the reason which refers to the relevant pregnancy. So for each woman only one value. I was thinking, you could build a loop in the sense of calculate new variable in such a way that loop i is taken at index i.

I could of course do it by hand, but with a VPN count of over 3000 it will obviously take considerably longer.
I hope someone can help me! This is an example dataset with less loops and VPN:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do repeat` to loop and catch the value you need this way:

```
do repeat vr=Loop_1_R to Loop_5_R/vl=1 to 5.
   if Index=vl reason=vr.
end repeat.
```